# changed PATH variable still old location pointed out bash: bad interpreter

Tags: anaconda, spyder, bash, installation-path

Recently my anaconda/python installation was moved from worspace01 to workspace02 partition in linux. I have changed all the environment variables manually still it shows there is a conflict with the old address. Did I miss out somewhere?

```
[nahiyank@venus]$ spyder
bash: /local/workspace02/nahiyank/anaconda/bin/spyder: /local/workspace01/nahiyank/anaconda/bin/python: bad interpreter

[nahiyank@cc08]$ $PATH
bash: /local/workspace02/nahiyank/anaconda/bin::/local/workspace02/nahiyank/anaconda/bin:/local/workspace02/nahiyank/anaconda/bin:/local/workspace02/nahiyank/anaconda/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/var/cfengine/bin:/home/u13/nahiyank/bin:.: No such file or directory


[nahiyank@cc08]$ cat .bashrc | grep anaconda
export PATH="/local/workspace02/nahiyank/anaconda/bin:$PATH"
```

However, my python is working perfectly which is using the same anaconda framework

```
[nahiyank@cc08]$ python
Python 3.6.0 |Anaconda 4.3.0 (64-bit)| (default, Dec 23 2016, 12:22:00) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

I have also tried to run the spyder executable directly from GUI

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with anaconda, but from the error message it looks like `spyder` is a python script with a shebang line that specifies the old path to the python interpreter. Something like this:

```
#!/local/workspace01/nahiyank/anaconda/bin/python
```

...and since the python interpreter isn't there anymore, it can't be found and you get the "bad interpreter" error. There may also be other hard-coded references to the old location. You can search for references to the old location with:

```
grep -R '/workspace01/' /local/workspace02/nahiyank/anaconda
```

It's probably possible to fix them by editing the affected files, but reinstalling might be simpler (as I said, I'm not familiar with anaconda).

It's not related, but your `PATH` also has some problems. /local/workspace02/nahiyank/anaconda/bin is listed 4 times (!), along with a blank entry (see the "::" part?).  We'd have to see more of your shell init files to figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

Anaconda is *not* a portable distribution, i.e. you  need to reinstall it in your new location for it to work again.

Answer (score 0):

- This is definitely a path issue
- Did you check `echo $PATH`
- the value of $PATH should have the substring of the anaconda path which is `local/workspace02/nahiyank/anaconda`
- If the new anaconda path is not set in $PATH then go to .bashrc file and set the `PATH` there by PATH="and_the_value_of_the_path_plus_anaconda_path"
- This should solve the problem
- Another easier solution will be to reinstall anaconda
- If you are reinstalling than i would suggest not to move the folder because in anaconda files are hardcoded and on moving thy still point to old location